# Процедура вывода результата нескольких значений для одного аргумента

Tags: дата, sql

Необходимо выполнить процедуру, которая имеет один входной аргумент формата "дата", но, запуская процедуру, нужно, чтобы в итоге был выведен результат за несколько дат.
То есть хочется видеть: 
exec наименование процедуры '20141001','20141001',
где перечислены не аргументы, а несколько значений одного (единственного) аргумента.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте таблицу (временную), которую наполняйте нужными датами.
В хранимой процедуре обращайтесь к этой таблице.